# R function to set different treatments to either 0 or 1

Tags: r

I have a character vector (called plots in the example) with the names of different treatments, all controls contain the letter "c" while all other treatments contain the letter "r". I would like to set all the controls to 1 and all the other treatments to 0.

I am a complete beginner in programming and I am working with an old code, where they did this with the code below but it doesn't work. I think the `str_match()` function in R works slightly differently and can't be used to solve this, any ideas how I could do this?

```r
trt = map_int(plots,StrMatch,str1="c")
```

Thanks!

Comment: `trt <- as.integer(grepl('c', plots))`?

Comment: @jdobres Saw your comment after posting my answer. I just not want to steal credit. >.<

Comment: @jdobres Great, works well, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `grepl` to check whether the letter is contained in the `plots` vector or not and then convert to an integer vector. This should work:

```r
### Sample data:
set.seed(314)
plots = paste0(sample(c("c", "r"), 10, TRUE), 1:10)
plots
#> [1] "r1"  "r2"  "c3"  "r4"  "r5"  "r6"  "r7"  "r8"  "c9"  "c10"

### Now convert:
trt = as.integer(grepl(pattern = "c", x = plots))
trt
#> [1] 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: sorry, didn't read carefully enough and missed that you were talking about a vector and not a column.

I don't know what your data looks like, so I'm just guessing (please provide some sample data next time).

You can use [dplyr](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) from [tidyverse](https://www.tidyverse.org/), those are a set functions designed to make your tools for data manipulation and visualisation ([ggplot2](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/)) more consistent (and perhaps easier to learn):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# example data
data <- tibble(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  plots = c('c_med0', 'r_med1', 'r_med2'))

data
## A tibble: 3 x 2
# id plots 
#     <dbl> <chr> 
#   1     1 c_med0
#   2     2 r_med1
#   3     3 r_med2

result <- data %>%
  mutate(
    treatment = str_detect(plots, 'c'))

## A tibble: 3 x 3
# id plots  treatment
#     <dbl> <chr>  <lgl>    
#   1     1 c_med0 TRUE     
#   2     2 r_med1 FALSE    
#   3     3 r_med2 FALSE

result

# or
result <- data %>%
  mutate(
    treatment = ifelse(str_detect(plots, 'c'), 1, 0))

result
## A tibble: 3 x 3
# id plots  treatment
#    <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
#  1     1 c_med0         1
#  2     2 r_med1         0
#  3     3 r_med2         0
```

Be careful about what is in your column `plots`, the code above only looks for a `"c"` and decides to give column `treatment` a "0" or "1". Perhaps with a more accurate descriptiont of `plots` you could identify a more robust way to identify the treatment.

If you would like to have the "0" and "1" in column `plots`, the code would look like this:

```r
result <- data %>%
  mutate(
    plots = ifelse(str_detect(plots, 'c'), 1, 0))

result
```

with result:

```r
# A tibble: 3 x 2
     id plots
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2     0
3     3     0
```

**Explanation as you said you are beginning:**
`mutate()` can change columns or add new columns, so we are adding column `treatment` or changing `plots`.
`str_detect(COLUMNAME, "WHAT_TO_DETECT")` finds out if the column `plots` contains "c" and returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`.
To change this into "0" or "1" you can use `ifelse(CONDITION, VALUE_ON_TRUE, VALUE_ON_FALSE)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for the good explanation!